# Create record-level security in OrientDB

Tags: database, security, acl, orientdb, sql-grant

Is there a way in OrientDB to grant/revoke access to specific records? For example, I have a class `Post` and would like only the `owner` of the post to have write access (**UPDATE and DELETE**) and everyone else to have read access.

According to [the security documentation,](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Grant) I can only find a way to do this down to a class or cluster level.

Comment: i think your answer is here https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Security#record-level-security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at: [Record Level Security](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-docs/blob/master/Security.md#record-level-security). If your class extends ORestricted this behavior is automatic. To allow other user to only read your record, add the OUser's RID into the collection field `_allowRead`. If the resource has rid #34:44 and the user you want to allow has rid #9:3 do this:

```
update #34:44 add _allowRead = #9:3
```

You can also add a ORole's rid to allow to all the users that have that role to read that record.